# Referencing a query in the WHERE clause of another query

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to first apply `Query(Importrange())` to the same file/cell range referenced in the code below, but then in the WHERE clause I would like to filter by the whole block of code below.

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J-751Pcc-N-5pS9o0P6tL_V6RfQElnqwh6xMEbofNUc/edit#gid=99687751","Combined!A:D"),"SELECT UPPER(Col2),Col3 label UPPER(Col2) 'Supplier'")),"Select Col")
```

I tried the below but got a value error:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J-751Pcc-N-5pS9o0P6tL_V6RfQElnqwh6xMEbofNUc/edit#gid=99687751","Combined!A:D"),"Select * where Col3 like '"&QUERY(UNIQUE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J-751Pcc-N-5pS9o0P6tL_V6RfQElnqwh6xMEbofNUc/edit#gid=99687751","Combined!A:D"),"SELECT UPPER(Col2),Col3 label UPPER(Col2) 'Supplier'")),"Select Col1")&"'")
```

In SQL this would be a simple job of `SELECT * from Table T where X IN (SELECT...)` but not sure how to do it in Google Sheets' query language

Comment: Could you share a sample sheet to have a better picture of what you are trying to do ?

Comment: The Google Sheets QUERY function lacks the 'in' clause of a full SQL implementation, so you can't specify multiple 'wheres' this way - the usual approach in Sheets to this situation is to use 'matches' instead and then JOIN the items from the internal QUERY with | characters using string manipulation. But it's difficult to give a specific formula without seeing example data.